# c++ : How does std::sort a vector of equal elements based on weak ordering principle

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I am trying to understand how weak ordering works by reading this article : https://medium.com/@shiansu/strict-weak-ordering-and-the-c-stl-f7dcfa4d4e07

The main take away from it is :

Then for strict weak ordering we must have
For all x:

```
x < x is never true, everything should be equal to itself
If x < y then y < x cannot be true
If x < y and y < z then x < z, the ordering should be transitive
If x == y and y == z then x == z, equality should be transitive
```

How would the below code work ?
For example , if someone compares x1 and x2 my compare function will return false for both func(x1,x2) and func(x2,x1). Then weak ordering is broken because rule number 2 is broken I think . Is my understanding incorrect ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct x
{
    int a ;
    x()
    {
        a = 3;
    }
};
bool func(const x& x1,const x& x2)
{
    if (x1.a < x2.a )
      return true;
      
    return false;
}
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   std::vector<x> vec;
   x x1 , x2, x3 , x4 , x5, x6, x7;
   x1.a = 5;
   x2.a = 5;
   x3.a = 5;
   x7.a = 5;
   vec.push_back(x1);
   vec.push_back(x2);
   vec.push_back(x3);
   vec.push_back(x4);
   vec.push_back(x5);
   vec.push_back(x6);
   vec.push_back(x7);
   
   std::sort (vec.begin(), vec.end(), func);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If both comparisons of two elements are false the two elements are equal.

Comment: Coding note: `if (x1.a < x2.a) return true; return false;` should be written `return x1.a < x2.a;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is good.

When the values `x1` and `x2` are compared, rule 2 is satisfied: The rule says "IF x < y, THEN something else". Since the IF part is false (`x1` is not less than `x2`), the entire statement is true.

That is how implications ("IF ... THEN ...") work. It is a basic rule of mathematical logic: when the precondition is not satisfied, the entire statement is true.